# Leaks in NavigationView/List/ForEach with Dynamically Generated Views

Tags: swift, swiftui, memory-leaks, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationview

If you create a very simple example that shows a lot of leaking object within the SwiftUI code if you nest `NavigationView/List/ForEach` and return different types of views in the `ForEach` closure.

```
import SwiftUI

class MyStateObject : ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var items:[Int]
    
    init() {
        self.items = Array(0..<1000)
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var stateObject = MyStateObject()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(stateObject.items, id: \.self) { item in
                    
                    if(item % 2 == 0) {
                        Text("Even \(item)")
                    }
                    else {
                        Image(systemName: "xmark.octagon")
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I strongly suspect this is a bug in SwiftUI but **I wanted to ask if I am doing anything wrong here**.

You can see the leaks by attaching Instruments. It will show immediately and increase if you scroll through the list.

Interestingly, it seems the leaks don't happen if

- you remove the `NavigationView` from the hierarchy.
- you only supply one type of `View` in `ForEach` (and don't branch via if/else).
- the list of items you want to show is small (100 does not seem to result in leaks).

*(Tested on XCode 12.5 and iOS 14.5 Simulator and Device,)*

Since in my app I am pretty much reliant on this kind of hierarchy, I am very open for some suggestions on how to avoid the leaking.

Comment: I have answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67611933/921573

Comment: I can't reproduce the leak using Xcode beta. can you show some diagnostics on the leak. what is the allocation of?

Comment: I did file FB9333352. In XCode 13-beta3, it still shows up, in beta4 the leaks are gone. But I suspect this is a bug in Instruments beta4.

Comment: @Nicolas If the leak is gone in beta 4, wouldn't that make you think that they _fixed_ this bug in beta 4?

Comment: Because it is also gone if you build against a deployment target of 14.5 and run it on the 14.5 Simulator. (Ie. I am not using iOS 15 code at all, but the leak is still gone in Instruments.)